# Why is my Image losing data through my Python FTP program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, ftplib

My `Python` program sends an image to my web server through `FTP`, but occasionally upon arrival, partial data is lost from the transferred image. The program takes a screenshot every `x` amount of seconds and then uploads the image to the web server.

My web hosting provider thinks it must be coming from the `Python` program itself, so please let me know what I'm doing wrong to cause this issue.

**Image(What it looks like when pulled from the web server):** [image]

**Code:**

```
def ftp(self):  # Screen Grab and FTP Transfer

    new = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 50, 1366, 720))
    new = new.resize((1366, 700), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    new.save("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\screenshots\\capture.jpg")

    newOpen = PIL.Image.open("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\screenshots\\capture.jpg")
    newOpen.save("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\screenshots\\capture.jpg", format="JPEG", quality=40)

    tries = 10  # Denotes maximum try limit for retry attempts

    for i in range(tries):
        try:

            # FTP image to Web Server
            session = ftplib.FTP('server', 'user', 'pass')
            file = open('C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\screenshots\\capture.jpg', 'rb')  # file to send
            session.storbinary('STOR capture.jpg', file)  # send the file
            file.close()  # close file and FTP
            session.quit()

            value = "Updated. \nFailed " + str(i) + " Times\n" + str(self.tick)

            print value

            self.tick += 1

        except KeyError as e:

            if i < tries - 1:  # i is zero indexed

                continue

            else:

                raise

        break

    threading.Timer(5, self.ftp).start()
```

Comment: Did you check size of the file before and after upload? Do they match?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Credit is due to you because of your suggestion. By monitoring the file size, I was able to diagnose the issue. Thanks for the assistance. Also, huge fan of your software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the actual reason for this was due to me opening the `FTP` image from the web server before the actual transfer was complete. My solution was to add a `PHP` filter to my web server to only pull the image when it was above a specific size as to avoid the premature viewing of the file before the whole transfer completed.

It works perfectly now and I am glad that the problem was a simple programmatic fix

Comment: That was the reason I was asking aboit the size

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yep. I tried to acknowledge that in a reply to your above comment. Thanks Martin